# NSURLConnection directly writes to file

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurl

In my App I am reading remote files (at times 32MB each) and writing them into a files (Cache).

I would like to save memory in my app during the caching operation and write the data directly to a file, or if possible at chunks.

```
NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&resp error:&error];
```

and later

```
[data writeToFile:file options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error2];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the asynchronous variant of `NSURLConnection`. There you have to implement, among others, the `connection:didReceiveData:`-method which passes the data in chucks to your controller.

take a look at the [apple-example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html). They use their own buffer to fill the received data. In your case you should forward the data directly to your file.

Comment: `didReceiveData` and other methods have a note `Available in iOS 2.0 through iOS 4.3`. I haven't tried to use it in iOS 5 yet.

Comment: wow, you are right, thats a new information for me too. but there will be an asynchronous variant of `NSURLConnection` in future too. Does anyone know sth about a replacement?

Comment: No, I don't know of any new replacement methods yet.

Comment: It looks like some of these delegate methods have been moved to the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` and `NSURLConnectionDownloadDelegate` protocols. The closest thing to the `connection:didReceiveData:` mentioned above is `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didWriteData:(long long)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(long long)totalBytesWritten expectedTotalBytes:(long long)expectedTotalBytes`. It looks like it's writing to a file for you, so that should actually make things easier for the TS